# C Program bigneer

Tags: c

I am working on generate 100 random numbers and place them in a , numbers should be 0-999. I wrote my program and it didn't print the random numbers.
I appreciate any help.
 this is my code

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #defin S 100
   int main()
  {
int x;
int a [S];
a[S]=100;
for(x=0;x<s;x++){
    printf(a[x]);
}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Please take the [tour],  
learn asking good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,  
make a [mcve].  
If you are looking for help with debugging code see https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: `a[S]=100;` is outside the bounds of the array. `a[S]` may only be indexed from 0 to 99.

Comment: Hint: turn on compiler-warnings ('-Wall' for gcc).

Comment: An *uninitialised array* might be seen as "random" but is not considered to be "random" programmatically.

Comment: `printf(a[x]);` as @Paul said.

Comment: @Paul I do not think that -Wall will be needed to make a compiler complain about that code. Compiling will be sufficient. And I am still waiting for a question to be asked.

Comment: Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. The code posted has naive errors and typos and does not compile. Which particular error asked about? No question was asked and cannot be answered.

Comment: @Yunnosch youre right, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Two things: first,  `int a [S]; a[S]=100` exceeds the array bounds (max is `S-1`).
Second, `printf(const char* format, ...)` expects a format string, but you pass an integer value at the place of the format string (turn on compiler warnings!). So write `printf("%d ", a[x])`, and the program should at least print out some numbers (once you actually assign any numbers to `a`).

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define SIZE  100
#define RANGE 1000

int main(void){
    srand(time(NULL));

    int a[SIZE];
    bool chosen[RANGE] = {0};

    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i){
        int select = rand() % RANGE;//select 0..RANGE-1
        while(chosen[select]){//check duplicate
            if(++select == RANGE)
                select = 0;//reset
        }
        chosen[select] = true;//selected
        a[i] = select;
    }
    //result
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    puts("");

    return 0;
}
```